# Load data to service when it turns to online

Tags: javascript, offline, service-worker, indexeddb, progressive-web-apps

I am able to add data to indexeddb when it is offline using service-worker in PWA but want to add the same data to service when it comes online(means i want to store the data into database by calling service). How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear. There are two interpretations of it and I'll try to answer for both.

1. Question - You want to use service worker in both offline and online cases.

Answer - There shouldn't be any problem in doing it the same way.

2. Question - How can you send the data to server, which was saved in IndexedDB when the app was offline.

Answer - You want to use [Background Sync](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/12/background-sync).

If there's any different requirement which you may have, please feel free to ask but try to ask it a bit clearly. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much. my question is like i have stored data in indexeddb when it was offline, but whenever i went to online i need to post data to server.

Comment: Cool. Then background sync is what you are looking for. I have mentioned that in my answer. Have a great day!

Comment: but how to call post method? and how to check offline or online? please if you have any code examples or live examples share with me.

Comment: @prasanna You have to refer to the Background sync link in the answer. It has all that you need. In case you didn't realize that's a link, here it is -> https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/12/background-sync